# What is the alternative of LocationClient?

Tags: java, android

I have no problem in all the code for background GPS, but I only have problem in the part of LocationClient (it can't be resolved)

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
    if (location != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        noti.setContentTitle("Sks Location Client");
        noti.setContentText(location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
        // noti.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_la);

        notificationManager.notify(1234, noti.build());

    }
```

Here is the part that cannot be resolved :

```
Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

Comment: look for FusedLocationApi its the newer api may be solve your issue

Comment: Use Google Play Service's FusedLocationApi which is gives better and accurate result in an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

LocationClient is deprecated, you have to use GoogleApiClient.